# Calculate number of data received in past 30 seconds

Tags: javascript

I have a websocket where i receive price of stock randomly like 300ms or sometimes 1 second.I want to calculate how many price I received in past 30 seconds only.

```js
var arr = [];

function onReceive(price) {
 var timestamp = Number(new Date());
  arr[timestamp] = [];
  arr[timestamp].push(price);
  
  if (arrarr[timestamp].length > 1000) {
    arr.shift();
  }
}
```

Now I just want to count how many price is received in last 30 seconds , I cannot come up with any logic.

I tried something like slicing last 30 items in array and calculating difference between last time stamp and -30 timestamp , which tells me how much time it took to receive 30 price ticks ,but i dont know how to calculate how to find how many ticks received in past 30 seconds , any ideas please.thank you.

```
 arr[timestamp][arr[timestamp].length-1].key-arr[timestamp][0].key;
```

Comment: Seems like a bad idea to create a sparse array with timestamp keys. What's the format of the timestamp? If it's unix time, your array length will immediately exceed 1548646220 something.

Comment: 1) Sort the array by timestamp 2) Take 30 seconds of most recent timestamp 3) Iterate the array and ignore any item that has a timestamp outside of the 30 second boundary.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Sort the array by timestamp? It's already sorted by timestamp.

Comment: Hi , It is current timestamp , I have updated my question, it is just demo i will create object if necessary , thank you.

Comment: Thank you for updating your question. The only thing that is currently still unclear, is the following: was it a design choice to use a sparse array in this case? There might be valid arguments both for and against, but without knowing if that's what you actually intended to do, it's not possible to say which solution would be appropriate for you.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Then, I guess step one can be skipped? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would create some sort of named instance for a log item, holding the UNIX timestamp and the price.

To retrieve anything in the last X seconds, you'd get the *current* UNIX timestamp, subtract `X * 1000` from it, and <strike>use `.filter()`</strike> do a reverse iteration to retrieve all items where the timestamp is greater than that.

**EDIT:** As Robby pointed out, there's no need to search through the entire array as the timestamps are guaranteed to be in increasing order. By iterating in reverse, we can exit the loop when we find the first result outside of the desired window.

```
var priceLog = [];

function PriceLogItem(price) {
  this.price = price;
  this.timestamp = new Date().getTime();
}

function onReceive(price) {
  priceLog.push(new PriceLogItem(price));
  if (priceLog.length > 1000) log.shift();
}

function getPriceLogsSince(secondsAgo) {
  let millisecondsAgo = secondsAgo * 1000;
  let time = new Date().getTime() - millisecondsAgo;

  let result = [];
  for (let i = priceLog.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (priceLog[i].timestamp >= time) result.push(priceLog[i]);
    else break;
  }
  return result;
}

//Usage
let priceLogs = getPriceLogsSince(30);   //Get all logs within past 30 seconds
console.log(priceLogs);
```

Comment: Since the timestamps are guaranteed to be increasing, a reverse iteration of the array would be a lot more efficient than using `filter()`.

Comment: Hi , I just need count of past 30 seconds , i can just return the count right ?

Comment: On the bottom, simply change the `console.log(priceLogs)` to `console.log(priceLogs.length)`. Or if you would prefer to return the length from the function instead, that works too.